# Convert Duration to Seconds in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table `data` in SQL which shows the user and the duration, but the duration is some times in pure seconds, while some is mixed between minutes and seconds

```
    User   |  Duration
--------------------------
      A    |  3:20
      B    |  :38
      CX   |  1:43
      V    |   45
      B    |  6:35
     ...   |  ....
```

Desired output (pure seconds)

```
    User   |  Duration
--------------------------
      A    |  200
      B    |  38
      CX   |  103
      V    |  45
      B    |  395
     ...   |  ...
```

I have been trying different functions in SQL, but yet to find one that works with both the minute portion and the seconds portion

Comment: Show your code and attempts to solve your issue

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: @jarlh the data type for duration is varchar

Comment: @dfundako I am currently away from the computer that has the code but I tried using DATEADD, CAST, CONVERT but I keep getting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to convert the string to a time type and then use time arithmetic:

```
select datediff(second, 0, cast('00:' + right('0' + duration, 5) as time))
```

Another method uses just string and number operations:

```
select cast(left(duration, charindex(':', t) - 1) as int)*60 + cast(right(duration, 2) as int)
```

Comment: That first method is SO COOL